# CWAC-CAM2 how to set resolution for photo?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to use the `cwac-cam2` library to take a picture. I don't know how to set low resolution. Currently the picture taken is at maximum resolution.

This is what I tried:

```
    Intent i=new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(getActivity())
            .facing(CameraActivity.Facing.BACK)
            .to(new File(tmpCameraPic))
            .debug()
            .updateMediaStore()
            .build();

    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no resolution control with CWAC-Cam2 at this time. I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues/142) on this.